# Artifactory, fullDB vs Filesystem storage

Tags: artifactory

I am currently working with an Artifactory repository which uses the "fullDB" storage model, with all artifacts stored as Blobs in the database.  I know that the recommended approach is Filesystem storage, and I have found pages saying how to migrate.  What I am wondering however is what are the pros/cons?  Will I gain a lot by performing the migration?  Curious as to why it would have been set up using the DB in the first place.  Thanks.

Comment: Which DB are you currently using?

Comment: Oracle 12 I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is better to use the filesystem as opposed to the FullDB method for performance reasons. Retrieving a file (in blob format as you mentioned) from the DB, will take much longer than retrieving from the filesystem, either local or NFS. You should notice a big boost in performance from this. As a very rough estimate (please don't quote me on the number), it is about 40% slower to use the FullDB method. The reasoning for using the FullDB method is to have all of the storage necessary for Artifactory allocated to one spot, ie all the space you need for Artifactory exists on the DB and no where else. It may be that the team that set this up in the past liked the idea for simplicity.

There really is no other advantage to using the FullDB method, hence it is not often recommended.